# wxAUI Help - Auto hiding tabs

Tags: tabs, wxwidgets, wxauitoolbar

Can the wxAUI component of the wxWidgets Libary be configured to dock into "auto hiding tabs" like visual studio 2010's own interface does.

This is what I want, panels that can be auto hidden in tabs.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/vstabs.png/

This is what I get, panels that take up 1/2 space each and always remain on screen.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/wxtabs.png/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

wxAUI does not currently have any support for this, although it could be added without immense difficulty.